# Waiting for an event emitter in a loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, while-loop, request

I'm currently working on my first node.js application. It's basically a feed reader CLI for my very specific needs. But I'm stuck with it for now and I hope, you can help :)

So, I have written two modules: With the first one I handle the rss feeds, loading data from it. The second one is a parser to read the articles one my one and get some meta data from the html site. Now I have to make them interact with each other.

In a function of the first module I read the data from each entry of the XML, something like this:

```js
const FeedParser = require('feedparser'),
  Metas = require(__dirname + '/metas'),
  events = require('events');

var Feeds = function(file) {
  var entries = [];
}

Feeds.prototype = new events.EventEmitter();

Feeds.prototype.loadFeed = function(url) {
  var self = this;
  var fp = new FeedParser();
  var req = request({
    url: url
  });

  req.on('response', function(res) {
    var stream = this;
    if (res.statusCode === 200) stream.pipe(fp);
  });

  fp.on('readable', function() {
    var stream = this,
      item;
    while (item = stream.read()) {
      var metas = new Metas();
      metas.getDescription(item.link);
      metas.on('loaded', function(desc) {
        self.entries.push({
          title: item.title,
          description: desc,
          date: item.date,
          author: item.author,
          url: item.link
        });
      });
    }
  });

  fp.on('end', function(res) {
    self.emit('loaded', self.articles);
  });
}
```

In the function `meta.getDescription()` I basically perform another request on the url and parse the data with `cheerio` to get the `og:description` or `description` meta data from the HTML string.

Problem is, that I'd have to wait on the event to emit in the loop, but I already learned that it's not possible this way. So how can I solve it otherwise? Any Ideas?